# How do I properly use boost::optional with types with public member variables?

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

Here is a motivating example demonstrating what my problem is:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

boost::optional<Foo> opt_foo;

opt_foo->x = 1; // legal
opt_foo->y = 2; // legal

auto foo = opt_foo.get(); // legal (returns valid instance of Foo with x = 1 and y = 2)

if (opt_foo) // false
{
  ...
}
```

I understand that in order for the optional object to be initialized, I would have to use `boost::optional<Foo> opt_foo = Foo();`. However, I was surprised to see that if it is forgotten, I can still do all the things I marked as legal (especially `get()`). Was this intended behavior? Is there any way I can make `opt_foo` consider itself initialized without `boost::optional<Foo> opt_foo = Foo();`?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/quick_start.html) use of an uninitialised boost::optional object is [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and therefore should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `boost::optional` is implemented as a simple

```
struct {
  bool _present;
  T _t;
}
```

So whether you explicitly initialize or not the optional with a value, the storage for this value already exists, and in C++ we don't usually like to pay for what we don't need (eg. checking if an optional is present on each call of `operator->`).

It is duty of the developer to only try to access the optional value if it is present, as explained in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/quick_start.html):

> An attempt to extract the contained value of an uninitialized optional object is an undefined behaviour (UB). This implementation guards the call with `BOOST_ASSERT`. Therefore you should be sure that the contained value is there before extracting.

Actually your code should `SIGABRT` on the assertion, are you running it in debug mode?

You can use `value()` if you want to avoid any risk of UB (but you need to place that in a `try` block).

Comment: Not quite like that. The idea is to wrap T into a `union` with nothing, thus suppressing default construction while allowing storage allocation.

Comment: @RustyX: that's not what it is stated in boost documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/performance_considerations.html